# Remove multiples values of a single key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value, multiple-value

I have a dictionary which has multiple values for a single key

```
myDict = {1: {'id1', 'id2', 'id3'}, 2: {'id4', 'id5'}, 3: {'id6'}}
```

My desired output is

```
myDict = {1: {'id1'}, 2: {'id4'}, 3: {'id6'}}
```

How do I only keep the first key and remove the rest?

Comment: It looks like you have kept all the keys. Did you mean remove some of the values from the sets?

Comment: yes, yes. I want to keep the keys, and remove multiple values. Only keep the first value, removing the rest.

Comment: I don't know whether its defined which is the first value, being a set.

Comment: is it possible to iterate through the values
 and only keep the first value, removing rest?

Comment: Sets are not subscriptable. Therefore the concept of the "first" item in a set is moot. You could convert the set to a list and isolate the 0th element but it might not be the one you expected. For example: *list({'id1', 'id2', 'id100', 'id200'})[0] == 'id2'*

Comment: Yes, you can iterate through a set. You should give that a go and update the question with your attempt.

Comment: Is it possible to keep any 1 item ? removing rest?

Comment: @Codingamethyst You can remove items from a *set* by using its built-in *remove* function

Comment: Like for instance, I want to remove 2 ids from key 1 and 1 id from key 2, basically removing every id and keeping only one. if i look at the problem with different pov, its more of keeping 1 item only rather than removing variable items, i thought that approach would be easier

Comment: @Codingamethyst OK but how do you know which one to keep? Remember that the "first" one isn't necessarily what you might expect it to be

Comment: yeah, actually i have a word as key and its list of synonyms as value

Comment: Yes, I would create a new set with just one item picked from the previous set. (or indeed just pick one value and not create a new set).

Comment: I need to replace every instance of the key in a list of sentences with one of its synonyms

Comment: If you have words as keys and a list of other words as values, perhaps you should update your question to reflect this.

Comment: Okay i will do it

Answer (score 1):

As comments mention, there is no "first" value in a set. However, there are several ways to get one item from a set.

You could use `next(iter(v))` to get an arbitrary value in O(1) time. Eg:

```python3
myDict = {1: {'id1', 'id2', 'id3'}, 2: {'id4', 'id5'}, 3: {'id6'}}
result = {k: {next(iter(v))} for k, v in myDict.items()}
print(result)
```

This approach may choose a different item each time it is run. If you need to produce a consistent result, you could use eg `min`, as long as you're working with strings:

```python3
myDict = {1: {'id1', 'id2', 'id3'}, 2: {'id4', 'id5'}, 3: {'id6'}}
result = {k: {min(v)} for k, v in myDict.items()}
print(result)
```

Comment: Hey, I got the stopiteration error for this code. Is there a way to fix?

Comment: @Codingamethyst Are any of the sets empty?

Comment: yes, some of them got no value

Comment: Please update your question with all these details.

Comment: What behaviour do you want in the case that a set is empty?

Comment: Well I tried removing the keys for those empty sets, for some reason it only removed the first instance, i dont really need those keys

Comment: @quamrana yes, please give me a moment

Comment: Hey, it worked, i removed the empty sets , thank you.